# Integration relating to transported measures

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ two measurable spaces and $T\colon (\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to (\Omega',\mathcal{A}')$ measurable. Show: If $f\colon \Omega'\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and either non-negative or $f\circ T\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$ then it is
> >     $$
> > \int f\circ T\, d\mu=\int f\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1}).
> > $$

Hey, my idea is to prove that in 4 steps.

(1) Show the statement for $1_A$ with $A\in\mathcal{A}'$.

(2) Show the statement for non-negative elementar functions.

(3) Show the statement for measurable non-negative functions.

(4) Show the statement for any measurable functions $f$.

For (2) I can use the properties of the integral relating to measurable non-negative functions (such as monotony, linearity,...). For (32) I can use the approximation by elementar functions. And for (4) I can use the sepation $f=f^+-f^-$.

---

(1) Let $A\in\mathcal{A}'$ arbitrary. Then by definition
$$
\int 1_A\circ T\, d\mu=\int_{T^{-1}A}\, d\mu=\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\int 1_A\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1}).
$$

(2) Let $f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i 1_{A_i}$. Then by linearity of the integral for non-negative measurable functions and (1)
$$
\int f\circ T\, d\mu=\int\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i 1_{A_i}\circ T)\, d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\int 1_{A_i}\circ T\, d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i\int 1_{A_i}\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1})\\=\int\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i 1_{A_i}\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1}).
$$

(3) Let $f\geq 0$ measurable. Then there exists a sequence $(f_n)$ of elementar function with $f_n\nearrow f$. From this it follows that $0\leq f_n\circ T\nearrow f\circ T$. From this it follows (together with (2))
$$
\int f\circ T\, d\mu=\sup_n\int f_n\circ T\, d\mu=\sup_n\int f_n\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1})=\int f\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1}).
$$

(4) Let $f$ be any measurable function and $f\circ T\in\mathcal{L}_{\mu}^1$. Then it is $f=f^+-f^-$, whereat $f^+$ and $f^-$ are measurable, nonnegative functions. So one can apply (3), getting
with the linearity of the integral for measurable, non-negative functions
$$
\int f\circ T\, d\mu=\int f^+\circ T\, d\mu - \int f^-\circ T\, d\mu=\int f^+\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1})-\int f^-\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1})\\=\int f\, d(\mu\circ T^{-1}).
$$

---

Is my proof right?

Greetings

Miro

Comment: Looks fine. This is a very standard sort of measure theoretic argument.

Comment: Only LOOKS fine or IS fine? :-)

Comment: It's how I would do it.

Comment: Have some confidence, mathfemi!  You did good work, now be proud of it.